# How to pass a program and its arguments to startx

Tags: command-line, xorg

In terminal, I do like this and it works fine:

```
$startx google-chrome-stable
```

It brings up chrome (just as an example) fine. But lets say I want to do with some arguments:

```
$startx google-chrome-stable -incognito
```

It fails, because it thinks `-incognito` is an argument for startx rather than chrome.

Whats the solution?

Comment: You could try something like `bash -c "google-chrome-stable -incognito"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following command

```
startx google-chrome-stable -incognito --
```

---

From `man startx`

```
The special argument '--' marks the end of client arguments and the
beginning of server options.
```

Comment: THis does not seem to work for me.

"startx mono /app/app.exe --" results in only mono be run, without the file argument

Answer (score 1):

For others that may wonder, you should be using the full path to Google Chrome instead. If not, `google-chrome-stable` is passed as an argument to the default client.

To run Chrome as the client:

```
startx /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable -incognito
```

or, if you don't know where it is located:

```
startx `which google-chrome-stable` -incognito
```