# Unable to chain startx command

Tags: server, xorg

I have Ubuntu server 16.04. I've installed `xinit`, `openbox`, `virtualbox`, `pcmanfm` and a number of other apps.

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697978/how-to-pass-a-program-and-its-arguments-to-startx) I should be able to launch programs from tty in the following manner: `startx pcmanfm`.
But for me X just closes right after the start without error.
I did check the log file of the Xorg.
The last few lines of Xorg.0.log are:

```
[  5507.340] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  5507.340] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[  5507.346] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

There are no notable errors in the log,  `cat Xorg.0.log | grep -i "(EE)"` gives:

```
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  5507.185] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  5507.185] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  5507.186] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  5507.186] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[  5507.204] (EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed
[  5507.212] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

I'm able to run the `startx` without parameters and openbox session starts okay and all the above programms (midori,pcmanfm,virtualbox) do work when launched from inside session. After such session is terminated, the Xorg.0.log is basically the same, in particular, same errors are logged only difference being their timestamps.

If launch commands are put into `.xinitrc` programms are also launched.

Any further steps for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a direct answer to your question but may be an alternative. I guess your are aware that the standard Ubuntu desktop flavours to not use startx but lightdm service to start the desktop. You would have your specific reasons for your installations on top of the server.

I am running a server where I installed XUbuntu-minimal desktop, so I can run x-Window applications over SSH which is very convenient for editing larger config files or browsing with the file manager. I selected Xubuntu because its xfce is very lightweight on server performance compared to unity.

Installation is easy

```
sudo tasksel
```

select Xubuntu-minimal. Only issue is that it will start all the time into the desktop.

Here is how to change that:

1) In order to prevent the login to appear, the responsible DM (LightDM must be modified:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

```
start on ((filesystem
           and runlevel [!06]
           and runlevel [!03]
           and started dbus
           and plymouth-ready)
          or runlevel PREVLEVEL=S)
```

2) Change grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

```
 GRUB_DEFAULT=0
 #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
 #GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="3"
 # comment the next line to disable boot to graphical terminal
 GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should do it. You could care to create a new grub menu entry later. Instead of startx you start with.

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

If you like your could define an alias

```
alias startx = sudo service lightdm start
```

Hope it works for you.